# Split object into two object by keys

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
 {
      "clicked": 0,
      "delivered": 0,
      "effective": 0,
      "enqueued": 0,
      "errors": 0,
      "forwarded": 0,
      "read": 0,
      "received": 0,
      "recover_sent": 0,
      "routing": 0,
      "sent": 0
    }
```

I want to split it into two object, the first one need to have 4 properties: received, errors, sent and delivered;
the second one need to have the rest

Like this:

```
obj1 = {
 "received": 0
 "errors": 0,
 "sent": 0
 "delivered": 0,
}

obj2={
      "clicked": 0,
      "effective": 0,
      "enqueued": 0,
      "forwarded": 0,
      "read": 0,
      "recover_sent": 0,
      "routing": 0,
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind creating temporary variables to store the values of keys, you can simply use destructuring assignment using the rest pattern.

```js
const obj0 = {
  "clicked": 0,
  "delivered": 0,
  "effective": 0,
  "enqueued": 0,
  "errors": 0,
  "forwarded": 0,
  "read": 0,
  "received": 0,
  "recover_sent": 0,
  "routing": 0,
  "sent": 0
}

const {received, errors, sent, delivered, ...obj2} = obj0;
const obj1 = {received, errors, sent, delivered};

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd probably go the destructuring route, it's not clear whether the set of keys is known at build time.

You could achieve this with a dynamically acquired set of keys as follows:

```js
const data = {
  "clicked": 0,
  "delivered": 0,
  "effective": 0,
  "enqueued": 0,
  "errors": 0,
  "forwarded": 0,
  "read": 0,
  "received": 0,
  "recover_sent": 0,
  "routing": 0,
  "sent": 0
}

const obj1Keys = ["received", "errors", "sent", "delivered"];

const entries = Object.entries(data);
const obj1 = Object.fromEntries(entries.filter(([k]) => obj1Keys.includes(k)))
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(entries.filter(([k]) => !obj1Keys.includes(k)))

console.log(obj1, obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to encapsulate krzysztof krzeszewski's answer in an anonymous function to avoid temp global variables:

```js
const obj0 = {
  "clicked": 0,
  "delivered": 0,
  "effective": 0,
  "enqueued": 0,
  "errors": 0,
  "forwarded": 0,
  "read": 0,
  "received": 0,
  "recover_sent": 0,
  "routing": 0,
  "sent": 0
};

const [ obj1, obj2 ] = (o => {
  const { received, errors, sent, delivered, ...o2 } = o;
  const o1 = { received, errors, sent, delivered };
  return [ o1, o2 ];
})(obj0);
```

If you need to call it multiple times consider separating it in a dedicated and proper function (like "`pick_and_separate(obj)`").